# Make UIButton accessible (accessibility) in tableview header

Tags: ios, accessibility

I don't seem to be able to find anyone that has the same issue as me. All my tableview cells are perfectly fine for accessibility but my headers don't seem to. I have a button in my header view which just won't work for accessibility... Can anyone help me out with this?

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {


    UIButton *button = [[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(282, 10, 28, 28)] autorelease];
    button.isAccessibilityElement = TRUE;
    button.titleLabel.text = @"Informatie";

    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(infoButtonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell addSubview:button];
}
```

I realise that I paraphrased this horribly. What I mean is, the button is working and all, just not for users that have assistive touch enabled on their phones. The phone isn't 'showing up' with the voice that helps the disabled users out. 
And I do get the log error "AX ERROR: Could not find my mock parent, most likely I am stale."

Comment: this function needs to return a uiview.  sounds like you want to put a button in the uiview returned so it shows up in the header?  not sure I understand exactly what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I know it must return a header, this is just a section of code, showing how I create the button. The button is working for normal touch, it's just inaccessible for people with assistive touch enabled.

(I know it's a duplicate but I made a new one because of the age of the old one)

Comment: Now how is `cell` related to this? What are it's properties? Have you tried `self.cell` already?

Comment: The cell is working, the button is working. Both the cell and button are showing. 

I now realise that I paraphrased this question really horribly... What I mean is, the button isn't showing up for users that use assistive touch, like disabled people. Brb, editing start post.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't set the button's title by modifying the label's text directly. Instead, use `setTitle:forState:`, e.g.:

```
[button setTitle:@"Informatie" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Also, buttons are typically created with the class method `buttonWithType:` instead of `alloc`/`initWithFrame:`.

Comment: Still doesn't work... I do get the log error: "AX ERROR: Could not find my mock parent, most likely I am stale."